# How to execute multi query in python?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I want to execute the sql_query given in below function and doing this way :

```
def get_globalid(self): 
    cursor = self.connect()
    sql_query = "REPLACE INTO globalid (stub) VALUES ('a'); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as id"
    cursor = self.query(sql_query, cursor)
    for row in cursor:
        actionid = row[0]
    return actionid
```

connect() function I am using to make a connection and it is defined separately .The query function i am using above is to execute any query passed to it . It is defined as :

```
def query(self,query,cursor):
    cursor.execute(query)
    self.close()
    return cursor
```

It is not working properly . Is there anything I am missing ? Is there any mysqli function for python like that in php (multi_query) ?

Comment: Try returning `cursor.fetchall()` in your `query` function. Also have you have written `close` explicitly? You can directly do `cursor.close()` to close the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql-python can't execute semicolon separated multiple query statement.
If you are looking for `last_insert_id` you can try with this:

```
conmy = MySQLdb.connect(host, user, passwd, db)
cursor = conmy.cursor()
sql_query = "REPLACE INTO globalid (stub) VALUES ('a')"
cursor.execute(sql)
last_insert_id = conmy.insert_id()
conmy.close()
```

Comment: By this way how can I make sure that that I am getting that  id which was generated after this insert(replace) only ? Can't that be a different id if lot of other things are calling this function only very frequently ?

Comment: `connection.insert_id()` get the ID from the last insert on that connection. if you call this method after the insert or replace you can be sure that the returned id is your last generated id.

Comment: You can also use `last_insert_id = cursor.lastrowid` aftet `cursor.execute`.